# SQLite-based NSPersistentDocument in a sandboxed environment

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data, nspersistentdocument, appstore-sandbox

I'm attempting to bring a Mac app up-to-date with the new sandboxing rules in Lion. However, despite requesting `com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write` permissions, I'm getting errors. When I look in the logs, I see `deny file-write-create /Users/thom/Desktop/Filename.blah-journal`.

This makes sense given the sandboxing rules - the user selected a location for the SQLite store, and so writing to that location is allowed. However, SQLite maintains its journal file alongside the actual file, and writing to *that* is forbidden.

In which case, how can an SQLite-backed NSPersistentDocument ever work in a sandboxed environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same issue while exporting Quicktime movies, as it writes an "atomic" working file that fails under sandboxing. All you can do is file a radar at this point.

Comment: Done. I choose to believe they won't require entitlements with a broken NSPersistentDocument, so I've just turned them off to see how it all progresses...

Answer (score 0):

Warning: the workarounds for this floating on the Internet DO NOT work on Mountain Lion.